# game development menu

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, scenekit

I was wondering if there is a simple way to connect a game scene to my main storyboard so that my main storyboard can be a main menu, Or is it better to just use another scene?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are more choices; for example, you could consider using XIBs instead of a storyboard.

Then, your question is both not very detailed and also strongly personal preference/opinion dependent.  StackOverflow questions are meant for finding answers to detailed questions.

I'd say: Look at example apps, checkout videos/articles/books about app structure, and just get started.  You'll learn along the way.